# Change of Variable Formula in Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, change-of-variable

I'm studying the change of variable formula in Lebesgue integral, and I've found some similar materials in  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3874204/1118138).

Among the explanation, I'm not sure why $F \circ g$ is differentiable a.e

If it meant that $F \circ g$ is absolutely continuous, I guess there is some counter-example that makes the composition not absolutely continuous such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2406816/1118138)

What property makes the composition differentiable a.e? Any comments about this including my error (if exists) would be grateful. Thank you.

-additional-

I have additional questions regarding the answer.

**1:** I suppose when $f$ is real-valued function (actually I'm interested in this general case), I could define $f_n$ as follows and then apply rest of your methods (including DCT). Tell me if this is wrong.
$$f_n(x)  = \begin{cases}n &\text{ if } f(x) \ge n\\
-n &\text{ if } f(x) \le -n\\ f(x) &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases} $$

**2:** I think the prerequisite for this question is estimated to be the following statement; $f$ is integrable, and $g$ is absolutely continuous and increasing, then $f(g(x))g'(x)$ is integrable as well. This was my trial, which seems not perfect.

Suppose $g(x) = y$, then this leads to $g'(x)dx = dy$ (basic calculus). Then,

$\int |f(g(x))g'(x)|dx$

=$\int |f(y)|dy$ < $\infty$ (∵ $f$ is integrable)

But this doesn't look nice to show the integrability of $f(g(x))g'(x)$. Is there any other way to show $f(g(x))g'(x)$ is integrable? Or, is this enough to prove the integrability?

Answer (score 1):

Using notations from the question you originally cite, define the functions $F : g([a,b])\to\mathbb R$ and $G:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ by

$$F(x) = \int_{g(a)}^x f(t)\ dt\ \text{ and }\ G(x)=\int_a^x f(g(t))g'(t)\ dt $$

Where $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a strictly increasing absolutely continuous function and $f:[c,d]\supseteq g([a,b])\to\mathbb R$ is non-negative and integrable.

Now for any integer $n\ge 1$, denote by $f_n$ the truncation of $f$ to level $n$, i.e.
$$f_n(x) := f(x) \wedge n = \begin{cases}n &\text{ if } f(x)\ge n\\
f(x) &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases} $$

And accordingly denote by $F_n$ and $G_n$ the integrals $F_n(x) := \int_{g(a)}^x f_n(t)\ dt $ and $G_n(x) := \int_a^x f_n(g(t))g'(t)\ dt$.

Now for any $n\ge 1$ and $y, x\in g([a,b])$, we have

$$\begin{align*}|F_n(y)-F_n(x)|&=\left|\int_x^y f_n(t)\ dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_x^y|f_n(t)|\ dt\\
&\leq\int_x^y n\ dt\le n|y-x| \end{align*}
$$

Hence $F_n$ is Lipschitz continuous and therefore [$F_n\circ g$ is absolutely continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563040/let-f-be-lipschitz-and-g-be-absolutely-continuous-show-that-the-composition?rq=1), hence a.e. differentiable. Now you can argue as in the previous answer to see that $F_n\circ g (b) = G_n(b)$, that is
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f_n(t)\ dt = \int_a^b f_n(g(t))g'(t)\ dt $$
Now you can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem and conclude by letting $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got more questions about it, which is written in the main question below the "-additional-".

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your question 1., yes that's how you would define $f_n$ if you drop the non-negativity requirement. Regarding your point 2. you can argue by Fatou's lemma :
$$\int_a^b f(g(t)) g'(t)\ dt \le \lim\inf_n \int_a^b f_n(g(t))g'(t) dt = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t) dt <\infty $$

Comment: Thanks, but after I read the whole explanations, I found your comment is based on your final result $\int f_n(t) dt = \int f_n(g(t))g'(t) dt$. Before this final result, I think the integrability of $f(g(t))g'(t)$ should be proved first. But base on my understanding,  $\int f_n(t) dt = \int f_n(g(t))g'(t) dt$, as well as the expression in your last comment, already uses the fact that $f(g(t))g'(t)$ is integrable. Is there any other way to show the integrability of $f(g(t))g'(t)$ first?

Comment: And, if you've got some time to add some comments, you may use this link; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4698200/1118138   . Thank you.

Comment: The identity $\int f_n(t) dt = \int f_n(g(t))g'(t) dt$ did not rely on the integrability of $f(g(t))g'(t)$, so there is no need to "prove the integrability of $f(g(t))g'(t)$ first" to deduce it. Once that identity is shown, Fatou's lemma as applied in my above comment shows that $f(g(t))g'(t)$ is indeed integrable (and DCT shows that its integral is actually equal to that of $f(t)$)... I see that you have opened another question about the integrability issue, so if you have further doubts about what I just said just raise them there, as this is beyond the scope of your original question here.

Comment: (Side note : please [do not edit your question to add "additional questions"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19012/857384) after your original question has been answered. Just create new questions instead. See also [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31169/should-i-create-a-new-question?rq=1), [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/can-i-change-the-existing-question-to-a-new-one?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/question-edited-to-change-meaning?noredirect=1&lq=1) on meta)

Comment: Ah, alright, now I can see. Thank you for your answer.