# Change of variables in Lebesgue Integral, 2nd question

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, change-of-variable

I'm strugging to show the change of variable formula in Lebesgue integral. My original question is [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4694877/1118138).

I've found a similiar question [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3874204/1118138), and the author says $G$ is differentiable a.e, which means $f(g(t))g'(t)$ is integrable. The thing is, I have a difficulty showing this statement. Every other statement is understandable, except for the fact that $f(g(t))g'(t)$ is integrable. The whole explanation make sense under the integrability of $f(g(t))g'(t)$ I guess. But I don't think letting $g(t) = y$ and differentiating $y$ with $t$ is proper way, (my first idea).

Any other comments about the integrability of  $f(g(t))g'(t)$ would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: See comments of [this answer to your second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4447002/386889), where a reference is given.

Comment: Actually I'm reading Stein's Real Analysis and solving the sane exercise I guess, which asks $f(g(t))g(t)$ is integrable (notation is slightly different), and I have a difficulty showing the integrability of the function.

Comment: I think this process is similar to my approach for proving the measurability of the same function $f(g(t))g'(t)$. Then, I guess I can deal with the integrability, except for the last step; the general function using DCT. Does the last DCT mean the limit of $\int \phi_n$ is $\int f(g(t))g'(t)dt$, where $\phi_n$ is asimple function? If that's the case, how does the DCT guarantee the integrability of $f(g(t))g'(t)$? Just the limit of finite numbers does not mean the limit is finite, as far as I know.

Comment: For reference, I used this site https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044021/show-that-ffxfx-is-measurable to prove the measurability, which seems similar to your reference.

Comment: I think the proposed duplicate answered your question. As for your last doubt (knowing already that $(f\circ g)g'$ is measurable) about the finiteness of $\int(|f|\circ g)g'$: approximate $|f|$ by an increasing sequence of positive simple functions $\phi_n,$ then (MCT twice) $$\int_a^b (|f|\circ g)g'=\lim\int_a^b(\phi_n\circ g)g'=\lim\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}\phi_n=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}|f|<\infty.$$

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you so much.